# Is there any performance difference between macros and functions in Rust?

Tags: performance, rust, performance-testing, rust-macros

> In Rust Macros are executed at compile time. They generally expand
> into new pieces of code that the compiler will then need to further
> process.

But after macros compiled or before compiled is there any performance difference between normal function vs macros?

Comment: Can you give an example of a macro and a function you want to compare the performance of?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume you're talking about runtime performance. Compile-time wise macros are usually slower as they are compiled for each invocation.

Macros are like `#[inline(always)]` functions. This can be good or bad for performance, depending on lot of characteristics like number of calls to the code, code size or instruction cache pressure. Always benchmark before making a decision.

If you can use a function, prefer that. It can always be marked `#[inline(always)]` if deemed good for performance, while using more familiar syntax and faster compile times.